# Tomcat 6 doesn't serve webapps remotely

Tags: java, debian, tomcat6, ipv6, ipv4

Basically, I installed linky (text-based browser) and everything is working as it should

I found the problem here

```
/etc# netstat -an | grep LIST
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1167            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5433          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10050           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8123                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN
```

The problem is that tomcat 6 is listening on port 8123 (the one that I chose) only on tcp6 and not also on tcp (ipv4)

I dont have any .conf in /etc/sysctl.d/, but I have /etc/sysctl.conf, and here I added:

```
net.ipv6.bindv6only = 0
```

and rebooted, but nothing changed, it continues listening only on tcp6 (ipv6)..

I am on Debian squeeze:

```
Linux ma21641.plusserver.de 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun May 6 04:00:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Java:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.13) (6b18-1.8.13-0+squeeze1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

What could I do?

Comment: Ok, i created in tomcat6/bin the file setevs.sh, set it executable and restarted tomcat6

Now there is a new line

tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8123 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 

but unfortunately i cant still connect...

Comment: remotely it doesn't work but locally it works right!?

Comment: Right, ah I forgot, before in the setenvs.sh I wrote: CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

Comment: Its a firewall problem, if I stop it /etc/init.d/firewall stop, then the page load remotely...

This means that I need to add an exception, right? Somebody knows how?

Comment: *iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8123 -j ACCEPT*

Comment: you can get fancier than that regarding firewall rules, only allowing NEW packets and then having another rule allowing ESTABLISHED and RELATED packets in etc. but the above line may get you started.

Comment: @TacticalCoder You could post an answer